# Jets3t zipfile upload, stream being closed automatically

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, jets3t

I am uploading a zipped file through a multipart webform. I am using groovy and grails for the upload but code would look similar in Java(with spring) as well...

```
def processUpload(){
    def uploadedFile = request.getFile('payload')
    String vloc = "";
    String filename = ""

    if(!uploadedFile.empty){
        InputStream is = uploadedFile.getInputStream()
        java.util.zip.ZipInputStream zis = new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream(is)
        def zipentry = zis.getNextEntry();
        while(zipentry!=null){
            println zipentry.getName()
            if( zipentry.getName().indexOf(".")>0){
                amazonS3Service.put (zis, zipentry.getName(), session.uid, ".zyx", zipentry.getSize())
            }
            zipentry = zis.getNextEntry()
        }           
    }
}
```

Where `amazonS3Service.put` is as follows

```
String put(inputstream, name, uid, ext, length)
{
    String mime = mimeExtensionMap[ext.toLowerCase()]
    S3Bucket bucket = makeBucket(uid)
    S3Object s3Obj = new S3Object()
    s3Obj.setAcl AccessControlList.REST_CANNED_PRIVATE
    s3Obj.setContentLength length
    s3Obj.setContentType mime
    s3Obj.setDataInputStream inputstream
    s3Obj.setKey name
    s3Obj.setBucketName bucket.getName()
    s3.putObject bucket, s3Obj
    return name
}
```

It seems that s3.putObject bucket, s3Obj method is closing my stream because I am getting streamClosed exception. I need to get nextentry from the zipfile and thus the stream should not be closed!

I have tried to use byteArrayinputstream with zis.getBytes() but even getBytes() closes the stream!!

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would just unzip everything in a temp folder and upload the files afterwards.

Comment: That would cause too much maintenance on AWS servers!!